# Problem with helpers in Cake

Tags: cakephp, php

Notice (8): Undefined variable: form [[...], line 64]

Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in [...] on line 64

Greetings!

Was learning about the form helper in CakePHP and I can't figure out why it won't work out. I even included the helper in the controller 
`var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');` and it's not working. Can anybody see anything I might have missed? I'm really new to CakePHP and usually I have friends I can leach off of when it comes to stuff in PHP, but not with this particular framework...

All help is appreciated :)

Line 64 is nothing more than `<?php echo $form->create(); ?>` by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a 2.0 development version of CakePHP where the `$helper->method();` syntax is no longer supported. Change your syntax to `$this->Form->create();` or install a stable 1.3 release version of CakePHP.

Comment: there is no code to "turn that off", $form is a ref of $this->Form or the other way round.

Comment: In 2.0 helpers are no longer accessible as view vars (e.g. $form->create();)

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like I have a fair few things to make my cakephp app ready for 2.0!